# Terraform Google Cloud: Making VM instance IP public

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have been struggling with this for a couple of hours now, so I thought I might as well ask for proper help.
I am trying to provision a VM instance with a public IP, but it doesnt seem to work. After provisioning, the IP throws a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` if I want to navigate to it. I have read through the docs, but could not find anything useful. Here is my large config:

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("...")
  project = var.gcp_project_id
  region = var.gcp_region
  zone = var.gcp_zone
}

resource "random_id" "name" {
  byte_length = 2
}

locals {
  # If name_override is specified, use that - otherwise use the name_prefix with a random string
  private_network_name = "test-private-network-${random_id.name.hex}"
  private_ip_name      = "test-private-ip-${random_id.name.hex}"
}

# IP ADDRESS
resource "google_compute_address" "ip_address" {
  project = var.gcp_project_id
  region = var.gcp_region
  name = "test-ip-${terraform.workspace}"
}

## Private network
resource "google_compute_network" "test_network" {
  provider = google
  name     = local.private_network_name
}

# HTTP RULE
resource "google_compute_firewall" "test_http" {
  project = var.gcp_project_id
  name    = "test-http-${terraform.workspace}"
  network = google_compute_network.test_network.self_link
  direction = "INGRESS"
  priority = 1000

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["80", "5433", "8000", "9540", "9808"]
  }

  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  target_tags = ["test-http-${terraform.workspace}"]
}

# HTTPS RULE
resource "google_compute_firewall" "test_https" {
  project = var.gcp_project_id
  name    = "test-https-${terraform.workspace}"
  network = google_compute_network.test_network.self_link
  direction = "INGRESS"
  priority = 1000

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["443"]
  }

  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  target_tags = ["test-https-${terraform.workspace}"]
}

# SSH RULE
resource "google_compute_firewall" "test_ssh" {
  project = var.gcp_project_id
  name    = "test-ssh-${terraform.workspace}"
  network = google_compute_network.test_network.self_link
  direction = "INGRESS"
  priority = 65534

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["22"]
  }

  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  target_tags = ["test-ssh-${terraform.workspace}"]
}

# ICMP RULE
resource "google_compute_firewall" "test_icmp" {
  project = var.gcp_project_id
  name    = "test-icmp-${terraform.workspace}"
  network = google_compute_network.test_network.self_link
  direction = "INGRESS"
  priority = 65534

  allow {
    protocol = "icmp"
  }

  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  target_tags = ["test-icmp-${terraform.workspace}"]
}

# INTERNAL RULE
resource "google_compute_firewall" "test_internal" {
  project = var.gcp_project_id
  name    = "test-internal-${terraform.workspace}"
  network = google_compute_network.test_network.self_link
  direction = "INGRESS"
  priority = 65534

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports = ["0-65535"]
  }

  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  target_tags = ["test-internal-${terraform.workspace}"]
}

# RDP RULE
resource "google_compute_firewall" "test_rdp" {
  project = var.gcp_project_id
  name    = "test-rdp-${terraform.workspace}"
  network = google_compute_network.test_network.self_link
  direction = "INGRESS"
  priority = 65534

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports = ["3389"]
  }

  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  target_tags = ["test-rdp-${terraform.workspace}"]
}

# Redis RULE
resource "google_compute_firewall" "test_redis" {
  project = var.gcp_project_id
  name    = "test-redis-${terraform.workspace}"
  network = google_compute_network.test_network.self_link
  direction = "INGRESS"
  priority = 1000

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports = ["6379"]
  }

  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  target_tags = ["test-redis-${terraform.workspace}"]
}


# test COMPUTE ENGINE INSTANCE
resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance" {
  name = "${var.app_name}-vm-${terraform.workspace}"
  project = var.gcp_project_id
  machine_type = var.gcp_machine_type
  zone = var.gcp_zone
  tags = [
    "test-ssh-${terraform.workspace}",
    "test-http-${terraform.workspace}",
    "test-https-${terraform.workspace}",
    "test-icmp-${terraform.workspace}",
    "test-internal-${terraform.workspace}",
    "test-rdp-${terraform.workspace}",
    "test-redis-${terraform.workspace}",

  ]

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "ubuntu-2004-focal-v20210927"
      size = 500
    }
    auto_delete = true
  }
  # Private
  network_interface {
    network = google_compute_network.test_network.self_link

    access_config {
      nat_ip = google_compute_address.ip_address.address
    }
  }

  metadata_startup_script = file("startup.sh")

  service_account {
    scopes = ["storage-ro"]
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: 1) What are you trying to connect to and what command are you using? 2) I do not see the installation of a web server or other application when you create the instance. 3) Provide the contents of **startup..sh**. 4) Potential problem. You are setting the firewall rule priorities to be 65534 for some rules. They must be different numbers.

Comment: @JohnHanley Im not trying to connect TO anything, but rather setting up an instance with a public IP that can receive based on my firewall rules. :) Does this make sense? startup.sh is just echoing a hello into a textfile right now. I thought the instance can be reached with a public ip without a webserver, but that surely doesnt make sense.. :D

Comment: Does the VM gets created ? Can you ping it ? Can you connect to it in any way ?

Comment: My question is what are you connecting to inside the instance (service/port-number). If you want a webserver running, you must install and configure one.

Answer (score 1):

SSH into your VM and run a curl localhost, if you get 200 response that means nothing is wrong with your VM or webserver.

Your next step is to check firewall and tags. Check whether your firewalls are actually targeting your instances.

The error you are seeing is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/basic-webserver-apache#troubleshooting). In case you have nothing installed in your VM you can also check the apache server example in the same documentation.